# Incompatible types with inheritance Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to wrap my head around this inheritance problem I'm having. Here's my current situation:

[image]

So I have a planning that can be either a list of activities (class `Activities`) or a list of things to do (class `Todos`).
However, if I do this in `Todos`:

```
private List<Todo> todos;

public List<Activity> getPlanning(){
    return todos;
}
```

It says that the types are incompatible.

- Why are they incompatible?

Since `Todo` extends from `Activity`, aren't we certain that `Todo` provides at least the same functionality as `Activity`?

and perhaps more importantly:

- How do I adjust my design to *make things work*?

(I'm not an expert in UML so forgive me if there are some mistakes in my diagram)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Java allowed you to return your `List<Todos>` as a `List<Activity`, the caller could then add any `Activity` into it. Clearly, that must not be allowed to happen.

You could make the returned list read-only by changing the return type to `List<? extends Activity>`. This would disallow adding *any* objects to the list (except `null` or objects directly retrieved from the same list).

Comment: Thank you, this answers both my questions !

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the nightmare and poor implementation of generics in Java. Try using `public List<? extends Activity> getPlanning()`.